# How can I have optional default constructor?

Tags: c++, traits, sfinae

This class:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  A() : t(T()) {
  } 

  A(const T& t_) : t(t_) {
  }

  T t;
};
```

won't compile if T doesn't have default constructor.
This one:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  A(const T& t_) : t(t_) {
  }

  T t;
};
```

won't have default constructor even if T has default constructor.

I want to have both - If there's no T() I want no A().

I know that SFINAE have to be used. And that Boost.traits and Boost.enable_if can help, but I can't get it to work. Can Someone give me an example to this simple case?

Comment: What do you want A() to call on T if T has no default constructor?

Comment: If there is no T() I want no A() at all.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but are you sure the first one fails, *if you don't attempt to use the default version with a T that doesn't have default constructor*? Both GCC and Comeau are fine with it. How are you instantiating the class?

Comment: So you also have to deal with private default constructor (it is common to make it private to avoid its definition by the compiler). having said that, I'm  not sure you can...

Comment: What UncleBens says. Why bother at all? It will fail if you try to use the `A()` and there is no `T()`, and it will not fail if you don't try to use it. As another improvement: Currently your class requires a copy constructor for `T`. You can solve that by writing `t()` instead of `t(T())`.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions of class templates are only instantiated if you invoke them. If you never invoke `A::A()`, then the code invoking `T::T()` shouldn't be compiled in this code:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  A() : t(T()) {
  }
  // ...
};
```

Are you having trouble with this? If so, which compiler are you using?

That said, if the code using `A` invokes its default constructor, then the only way out I see is to move the creation of the `T` within `A::A()` into some traits class:

```
template< typename T >
struct default_a_ traits {
  static T default_construct()
  {
    return T();
  }
};

template <class T, class Traits = default_a_traits<T> >
struct A {
  A() : t(Traits::default_construct()) {
  }
  // ...
};
```

For classes not having a default constructor you can provide some traits class that provide means to create a `T` some other way:

```
struct my_special_traits_for_b {
  static T default_construct()
  {
    return read_b_from_db();
  }
};

typedef A<B, special_traits_for_b> AB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  A(const T& t_ = T()) : t(t_) {
  }

  T t;
};
```